# Merge vertically the content of .txt files

Tags: python, merge

I would like to merge the content of specific .txt files VERTICALLY  in a folder (directory) via one commant in python,

I have tried the following code but its no use (I mean it works, but the put the output is shown as one horizontal plot, and not multiple vertical lines)

```
import glob

read_files = glob.glob("mypath/finalR*.txt")

with open("result5.txt", "wb") as outfile:
    for f in read_files:
        with open(f, "rb") as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())
```

could you help me?

Comment: Is the entire output on 1 line? Or is the problem with just the last few lines of every file?

Comment: All .txt files that I want to merge have 1 line. I want to merge 25 .txt files. So, I would like the output to have 25 lines. Using the code I sent the output has 1 line (it merges the files horizontally and not vertically)

Comment: I think you just need to add a newline character `\n` to the text in each loop

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to note:

1. `b` is for opening a file in binary mode. You don't need this since you are working with text files.
2. Since you have only a couple of files, I suggest you read all the lines into a Python list and write into the output file once.

Keeping these in mind, the solution now looks like the following:

```py
read_files = glob.glob("mypath/finalR*.txt")

lines = []
for file in read_files:
    with open(file, "r") as f:
        lines.extend(x.strip() for x in f.readlines())

with open("result.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(lines))
```